# Explanation needed for Recurring anomaly in Photo's

Tags: error

I took 9 photo's roughly 1 to 6 minutes apart with a **FUJI FINEPIX S4400** set at *Sunset mode*.The scenery is the horizon with a light overcast sky with the sun about an hour away from setting.I estimate the clouds had a transparency of 20 percent.And 90 percent of the sun was visible.All 9 photos resulted with a in the Sun having a odd angular flare that I have never seen before.I will post 3 of the 9 pictures, I used a solar filter on one and the other two are originals.

> **My question is, Were all 9 images correctly displayed? or rare anomalies?**
>   *Please provide a photo that distinctly resembles the images I captured if answering the question*

[image]

[image]

[image]

The closest image I can find that resembles the photo anomalies are digitally designed and named anamorphic flares.My photo's were not designed so this rules out this type of anamorphic flare.
[image]

Another way to capture a anamorphic flare is to use a special anamorphic flare lens that compresses the image giving the effect.I did not use a anamorphic flare lens so this rules out this type of anamorphic flare.

Letus35 AnamorphX Adapter High Flare, Anamorphic Converter, 114mm Clamp On, Super 35 cost-$1,694.95

[image]

> **Note Both of these Anamorphic Converters capture horizontal and perpendicular flares, all 9 of my images have a horizontal flare.**

Comment: It is called [lens flare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens_flare)

Comment: @ChrisStillwell-Can you provide 2 links with a exact  lens flare matching my photo's? There must be thousands available with this lens flare right.

Answer (score 3):

So, I think it is lens flare and, no, that does not mean that there should be thousands of other images with the same flare. The flare can be caused by a few different things including flaws in the glass, substances on the surfaces, scratches in the coating, etc.

Issues with the surface of various optics are usually not that big of deal, there's a blog post on Lens Rentals showing how even major damage to the front element can have minimal effect, but bright light sources are likely to expose them if they exist. The Sun is a pretty bright light source.

Comment: I have literally taken hundreds of photos of the sun with this camera for the last 3 years, most at sunrise and sunset and have never noticed a anomaly like this and all 9 photos had the same exact anomaly. This is why I posted the question.

Comment: @TheVoid - Still looks like flare. What do you think flare is? It's an anomaly and it's usually caused by either a flaw in the lens, an issue on the surface, or the angle you're shooting at.